# Unable to display an image using React JS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, image, visual-studio-code

I'm starting out with React JS with a code to display a picture, a header tag and an ordered list. Here's the JS code:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
const test = (
    <div>
        <img src="./balloons.png" width="100px" alt=""/>
        <h1>Names</h1>
        <ol>
            <li>A</li>
            <li>B</li>
            <li>C</li>
            <li>D</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
)

ReactDOM.render(test,document.getElementById("root"))
```

Here's the index.html part :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "root"></div>
        <script src = "index.pack.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, the code runs and displays an output like this in the react app. I can't see the pic I uploaded.[image: Output screen]

Here is the folder arrangement in VS Code if it would help:

[image: Folders]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to import the file https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you save the images in the **public** folder, it works fine

Answer (score 1):

try to import Image
and use it in src like that:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
// try to import image
import YourImageUrl from './balloons.png';

const test = (
    <div>
        <img src="{YourImageUrl}" width="100px" alt=""/>
        <h1>Names</h1>
        <ol>
            <li>A</li>
            <li>B</li>
            <li>C</li>
            <li>D</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
)

ReactDOM.render(test,document.getElementById("root"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have import the image first. Write js code like this

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import balloons from './balloons.png'
const test = (
    <div>
        <img src={balloons} width="100px" alt=""/>
        <h1>Names</h1>
        <ol>
            <li>A</li>
            <li>B</li>
            <li>C</li>
            <li>D</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
)

ReactDOM.render(test,document.getElementById("root"))
```